# Parse one or more expressions with helpful errors

Tags: python, parsing, ebnf, peg, grako

I'm using grako (a PEG parser generator library for python) to parse a simple declarative language where a document can contain one or more protocols.

Originally, I had the root rule for document written as:

`document = {protocol}+ ;`

This appropriately returns a list of protocols, but only gives helpful errors if a syntax error is in the first protocol. Otherwise, it silently discards the invalid protocol and everything after it.

I have also tried a few variations on:

```
document = protocol document | $ ;
```

But this doesn't result in a list if there's only one protocol, and doesn't give helpful error messages either, saying only `no available options: (...) document` if any of the protocols contains an error.

How do I write a rule that does both of the following?:

1. Always returns a list, even if there's only one protocol
2. Displays helpful error messages about the unsuccessful match, instead of just saying it's an invalid document or silently dropping the damaged protocol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468395/improving-errors-output-by-grako-generated-parser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35420025/545637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
document = {protocol ~ }+ $ ;
```

If you don't add the `$` for the parser to see the end of file, the parse will succeed with one or more *protocol*, even if there are more to parse.

Adding the *cut* expression (`~`) makes the parser commit to what was parsed in the closest option/choice in the parse (a closure is an option of `X = a X|();`). Additional *cut* expressions within what's parsed by `protocol` will make the error messages be closer to the expected points of failure in the input.